# Рандомайзер фоток телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
if message.text == 'Фотка'
   photo = open('Photo/photo.jpg', 'rb')
   bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Я хочу чтобы он отправлял не определенное фото а рандомное из папки, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random, glob

if message.text == 'Фотка':
   files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
   with open(random.choice(files), 'rb') as photo:
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

1. Использовал `glob`, чтобы получить список файлов.
2. Использовал `with open`, чтобы автоматом закрыть файл при выходе.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте названия всех фотографий в список и выбирайте случайный элемент списка:

```
import random

photos = ['photo.jpg', 'another_photo.jpg', 'photo.png']

if message.text == 'Фотка':
    with open(random.choice(photos), 'rb') as photo:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```